# Can't get selected option value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question is very simple, but unfortunately i can't solve it. So, I have this code:

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="taskGroupId" name="taskGroupId" onchange="refreshGridGroup(this.value)">
    <option value="all">All Task Group</option>
     <?php
         if ($this->arrSelectTaskGroup) {
           foreach ($this->arrSelectTaskGroup as $v) {
              if ($v['value'] == $this->defaultId) {
                   echo '<option value="'.$v["value"].'" selected>'.$v["name"].'</option>';
              } else {
                   echo '<option value="'.$v["value"].'">'.$v["name"].'</option>';
              }
           }
         }
      ?>
  </select>
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="downloadToXls()">Export To Excel</a>
```

I tried to get the option value:

```
function downloadToXls() {
    var a =$('#taskGroupId').val();
    alert(a);
}
```

But the alert was empty. I don't what's wrong with my code.Help me please...

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: replace $('#taskGroupId').val(); with $('#taskGroupId option:selected').val();

Comment: check if you are not repeating #taskGroupId id somewhere else, also what is refreshGridGroup method doing to value ?

Comment: after removing the refreshGridGroup method its working fine for me, here is the working JSfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/6gtrjma5/

Comment: @shiva I tried too but it still give empty alert

Comment: @JahangirAlam yes it show alert but it said `undefined` word

Comment: @Tushar I tried, but no error return or no red line

Comment: @A.T. refreshGridGroup for show datatable value based on selected value

Comment: @A.T. thanks for suggest ` 
check if you are not repeating #taskGroupId id somewhere else`. I change it into other name id and it works. Thanks~

Comment: Please check $this->arrSelectTaskGroup is empty not and your select list is populated or not